# How do the Void Aliens record knowledge without perceiving shapes?

Tags: information

The void aliens, as the name implies, live in the void of space. This environment is rather lacking in important shapes, and so the aliens cannot distinguish objects by shape. While many inventions can be defined in other more perceptible ways, writing will be impossible. Diagrams will also be hard to follow

Given this, how might these aliens record their inventions and such?

Comment: What sorts of things do they invent? Traditional deep-space creatures learn to do things with their vast yet diffuse energy bodies, but aren't tool users.

Comment: What inventions do they have without solid objects?

Comment: I think you need to say something about the nature of these aliens before this could possibly be answered. Are they energy beings made of the void itself? Or little animals floating around in space, eating the occasional hydrogen atom that happens to come their way? Normal aliens that just happen to like parking their spaceships in the middle of the void?

Comment: I don't see what "live in the void of space" has to do with "cannot distinguish objects by shape": Can they not perceive planets, stars, galaxies, nebulae, asteroids and each other? Do they completely lack any method of describing those objects / observations to each other? Do they have any methods of interaction at all? If they can communicate and interact with the environment, hook those abilities. If not... it seems hard to say much about "creatures" which have no way of either observing or interacting with their surroundings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stories and accounts have been transmitted orally for a very long time before the invention of writing.

The storyteller was a legitimate profession, together with other roles which were tasked with remembering and telling stories, for example priests.

Something similar can happen here: somebody will be tasked with remembering and transmitting the records of inventions and so on.

Comment: "Orally" suggests sound, and a "void" is unlikely ti have a medium that carries sound.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Outer space is a (very diffuse) gas.  If you are large enough and patient enough, speaking using it is possible.

Comment: @Klaus Æ. Mogensen "Orally" here could just as easily be electromagnetic waves or some other form of "signal"

Answer (score 3):

**They are not a visual species.**

This is actually quite common on Earth. Humans prioritize vision over our other senses, but this is in no way universal. Many land animals, such as dogs, place greater importance on smell, and burrowing creatures may focus on touch or vibration (a sort of "hearing"). Some animals don't have a sense of vision at all, often because they live in an environment with little or no light.

Taking all of that together, it's entirely conceivable that your aliens might prioritize some other sense, if there's no light to see by. Of course, vacuum doesn't give them much to go on - you can't smell or hear anything without an atmosphere, and you probably won't be touching or tasting much either. Therefore, you will probably want to **invent new senses** that are appropriate for that environment.

For the sake of argument, let's just suppose the aliens are telepathic. But what kind of telepathy? There's so many to choose from!

- Your aliens can make each other "hear voices" or other sounds (i.e. they can induce auditory hallucinations in one another). This is how telepathy is often portrayed in media, and it may be a nice "safe" starting point if you want your aliens to be familiar to readers or audiences.
- Your aliens can convey emotions to one another, without using words or having to explain them. I feel angry, I commune with you, you feel angry on my behalf (and/or you understand that I feel angry and why).
- Your aliens can show images to one another. But then you run into the "what images?" problem, so maybe this isn't such a great idea.
- Your aliens can directly transfer complex thoughts and ideas, without needing to express them in words or images. Consider the lucid dreaming in *Inception*, for example.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: That is not a header. It is a standalone paragraph. Making it a header will not improve accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

### They don't have a concept of "shape," but can still distinguish symbols by other attributes.

Consider the mathematical field of topology. A sphere is topologically indistinguishable from an ovoid, a cube, a star icosahedron, or any other solid shape with no holes in it—but as soon as you put a hole through it, it becomes something distinct, a torus. Perhaps your creatures see reality in a similar way, and could form a writing system based on related principles—in other words, **something quantified instead of qualified.**

The fundamentals of [knot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory) would be an easy way to form an alphabet of topologically distinct symbols in two dimensions, and the possibilities multiply as the number of dimensions goes up.

Answer (score 2):

Just as Klaus Æ. Mogensen pointed out, there are plenty of other ways to communicate information than shapes. Computers don't know anything about shapes either, but they have no problem storing and transmitting massive amounts of data using devices that can only record 2 states.

So, all you need is something that can represent at least two states. Presumably, these Void Aliens can perceive "brighter" and "darker", in some form of energy detection. It doesn't have to be humans' "visible" spectrum, it could be ultraviolet, or infrared, etc. Then you just need two different substances that either: A) reflect that radiation; or B) emit that radiation. Either way, the substances each transmit "less" or "more", "brighter" or "darker", "hot" or "cold", "glossy" or "matte"... whatever works, so long as there are two easily-discernible states. After that, all you need is a way to arrange them in a static sequence, where it's easy to start at one end of the sequence and "read" along to the other end, and you have a binary-encoded data.

And the best part is, it doesn't even have to be two "opposite" states. Maybe one substance "feels especially smooth", and the other "feels especially cool", and then you have both a writing system and The Fonz. :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Sound, light, electric charge, magnetic fields

You can record a series of sounds - notes, words, noises - which can then be played back - on the condition that there is a medium through which sound can travel, which there may not be in a 'void'.

Or you can record light of shifting color, luminosity and duration - even going beyond the visual spectrum to microwaves and gamma rays.

Or use shifting electric charges or magnetic fields. With magnetic fields, you can even use variations in direction (if there is any way to determine direction in the environment). Streams of ions could feasibly also be used.